# Using CSS only to zoom an image inside iframe

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

Is it possible to add styles to an image which inside an iframe on the page using CSS only?

The following css is not working:-

```
<style>
    iframe img
        {
            zoom: 0.8;
        }
</style>
```

I tried the following scripts:-

```
<style>
.zoomingAds
    {
        zoom: 0.8;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var i, frames;
        frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
        for (i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i)
        {
            var images = frames[i].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("img");
            frames[i].className += "zoomingAds";
        }
    });
</script>
```

But it's not working because I used Javascript and tried to access an iframe which get from google ads(another domain).

The error is:-

```
blocked a frame with origin "MyDomain" from accessing a frame with origin "htto://googlesyndication.com" protocols, domains and ports must match
```

Comment: You are not going to be able to do anything to the iframe content with javascript or with css if it is on a domain you don't have control over.

Comment: Yup, JavaScript cannot be used over foreign hosts. It's called [CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).